# Downgrade to a Palindrome

Tags: code-golf, string, palindrome

Given a string `s`, return the smallest contiguous substring you can remove to create a palindrome.

---

## Examples:

```
800233008   -> 2
racecarFOOL -> FOOL
abcdedcba   -> (empty string)
ngryL Myrgn -> "L " (or " M")
123456789   -> 12345678 (or 23456789)
aabcdbaa    -> c (or d)
[[]]        -> [[ (or ]])
a           -> (empty string)
```

Test case suggestions from users (if you find an edge case not listed, please post a comment):

```
aabaab      -> b    | Suggested by Zgarb, some returned "aa".
```

---

## Rules

- Only printable ASCII characters will appear in the input (no newlines, keep it simple).
- Not really a rule, but note `<>`, `/\`, `()`, `[]` and `{}` are not palindromes.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), smallest byte-count wins.

---

*+100 bounty has been claimed by Adnan*

Comment: Tesf case: `aabaab`

Comment: I think it will help keep questions accessible to more visitors if ingroup jargon like “CMC” is avoided (looking it up, it appears to stand for “chat mini challenge”, which I imagine means a small challenge posted in the chat room associated with this site).

Comment: Isn't ```[[]]``` a palindrome?

Comment: @Carl It may look like one, but when you reverse the characters, you get `]][[`. Consider that `aabb` is the same thing, just different characters.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien oooh, yes :)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR fixed.

Comment: What about `qrabbapo`? Then you need to remove from two sides, `gr` and `po` to obtain `abba`, or it would be considered as removing `qrabbap` or `rabbapo`?

Comment: @JavaGonzalezArribas the answer would be `qrabbap` or `rabbapo`, you must remove a ***single, contiguous substring***.

Comment: 7/12? if that is 2017-12-07, what kind of locale **are** you using? If that is 2018-07-12, that is a long way off...

Comment: @NH 7/12 is dec 7 in many european countries. Mine for instance

Comment: "*(will be awarded 7/12)*" huh?

Comment: **see**? I'm not the only one confused.  You didn't specify a locale, so please use a less ambiguous date (like the ISO 8601 version: 2017-12-07)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer HE MUST GO BACK IN TIME TO CLAIM THIS REWARD. Kidding, no idea what the heck I did there.

Comment: @NH. No, it's not that. 7/12 can either mean December 7 or July 12, both of which can't be applicable in any case. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
Ḣ;Ṫµ=Ṛ
0,0jŒṖÇÞṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkXWD3euOrTV9uHOWVwGOgZZRyc93DntcPvheUDh/w93bznc/qhpTeT//xYGBkbGxgYGFlxFicmpyYlFbv7@PlyJSckpqSnJSYlceelFlT4KvpVF6XlchkbGJqZm5haWXIkgBUmJiVzR0bGxXIkgPhABAA)

#### How it works

```
0,0jŒṖÇÞṪ  Main link. Argument: s (string)

0,0j       Join [0, 0], separating by s. This prepends and appends a 0 to s.
    ŒṖ     Build all partitions of the resulting array.
      ÇÞ   Sort the partitions by the helper link.
           As a side effect, this will remove the first and last element of each
           partition. The 0's make sure that not removing any characters from s
           will still remove [0] from both sides.
        Ṫ  Tail; extract the last one.


Ḣ;Ṫµ=Ṛ     Helper link. Argument: A (array/partition)

Ḣ          Head; yield and remove the first chunk of A.
  Ṫ        Tail; yield and remove the last chunk of A.
 ;         Concatenate head and tail.
   µ=Ṛ     Compare the result, character by character, with its reverse.
           A palindrome of length l will yield an array of l 1's, while a
           non-palindrome of length l will yield an array with at least one 0 among
           the first l/2 Booleans. The lexicographically largest result is the one
           with the longest prefix of 1's, which corresponds to the longest
           palindrome among the outfixes.
```

Answer (score 10):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

```
(0{::(-:|.)\.#&,<\)~i.@#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYq7DoIwGEb3PsUfSShNsKnUCxYxTk4YHgAY2kJRB0zKRLy8em2HL/nOyXk6M0MpgIGfS9hbiGQtPpS0NIrTU0t@D3qJHEErCtiUAkMKXwFmRmjQ9xckhSHxGXDOWMY5YzkusJV60NJe67ryJJXuh14r6f802qWC22LHydMm49vd/pAfQxUyJUPUNF0XDHZ/)

### Explanation

```
(0{::(-:|.)\.#&,<\)~i.@#  Input: array of chars S
                       #  Length of S
                    i.@   Range, [0, 1, ..., len(S)-1]
(                 )~      Dyadic verb on range and S
           \.               For each outfix of S of size x in range
        |.                    Reverse
      -:                      Matches input (is palindrome)
                <\          Box each infix of S of size x in range
             #&,            Flatten each and copy the ones that match
 0{::                       Fetch the result and index 0 and return
```

Comment: Perhaps you might want to choose `(;&quote f)&>` as the test harness verb?

Answer (score 7):

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>53</s> 51 bytes

Byte count assumes CP-1252 encoding.

```
±{a___,Shortest@b___,c___}/;PalindromeQ[a<>c]:={b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxNCoMwFIT3niK4LIJW@2N/EQpdFEWLSxF5iUEDGiHGhYiH6hV6MWuKbh7zzbyZGmRJa5CMwDR9PwNkWWbEZSMkbaWHFZH5jOYlgorxXDQ1fSdwvZP0fBvwOEWCcYm8DYrlrIpXw7iiqOragPGuVfAoQQCRVLTI9NCgIaS7lmU7jmW5uoEUzzklIJ5h6C8OYJLTnGBYmBei91HQi4IvztZ2dvvD0T3pxr@gGhjW/yRJ03VK18bpBw)

Defines a unary operator `±` (or a function `PlusMinus`). Input and output are lists of characters. The test suite does the conversion from and to actual strings for convenience.

Comment: Is `Reverse` then comparing that reverse to the original shorter than PalindromeQ? I don't know Mathematica, so no idea.

Comment: Good answer, but shouldn't one account for the splitting of strings and joining them back together in your character count?  `Characters@#/.{a___,Shortest@b___,c___}/;PalindromeQ[a<>c]:>b~~""&`

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn `Reverse[x={a,c}]==x` is two bytes longer. I don't know whether there's any shorter alternative.

Comment: @KellyLowder Lists of characters are valid representations of strings on PPCG. It's a bit awkward in Mathematica, where you wouldn't normally use that representation, but it's still valid. I'll dig up a meta post.

Comment: @KellyLowder I think [this is the accepted policy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/8478). The main reason why it's awkward in Mathematica is that Mathematica doesn't have an actual character type, so the characters end up being singleton strings.

Comment: OK, just asking.  I've put some posts on here that included the string splitting and concatenation.  If that's deemed unnecessary, so be it.

Comment: @MartinEnder I'm not sure if a list of singleton strings is allowed though, FryAmTheEggman's answer seems to have a score of -1.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
ā<Œ¯¸«ʒRõsǝÂQ}éнèJ
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP8wNWFiMWX//8SBPMWSwq/CuMKrypJSw7Vzx53DglF9w6nQvcOoSv//cmFjZWNhckZPT0w)

Comment: Interesting usage of filter there... We were trying to do an "a without b" type of deal, but if there was two instances of the substring, we'd get false negatives. Feels like we were over-complicating it now that I see this lol. Noice, I'll give you a 100 bounty in 2 days.

Comment: `ǝ` was seriously genius though.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
ŒḂ⁹Ƥ
çÐ€JN$Ẏi1ịẆẋ⁻Ṛ$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9qZWxsef//xZLhuILigbnGpArDp8OQ4oKsSk4k4bqOaTHhu4vhuobhuovigbvhuZok////YWJjZGVkY2Jh)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 97 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,p='	':min([s][:p[::-1]in p+p]+(s and[f(s[1:],p+s[0]),f(s[:-1],s[-1]+p)]or[p]),key=len)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LasMwEEXX6VfMThJWihT34QrcZVcp@YBBi/ErNY1lIXljQr7dlUxhGDhzD8P16/Izu3LbhvpGU9MRROlrdmBmGh3HaNF4NOao7ejAF94WPAK5DgceURsrfRFRWSEzZ01GTLvwws4BfQp@@7W@9U5swxwgQnrDKqVOZalUxSSwQG3fUvi6XM4ZqWm7vmsbyuCuYT3D9xquLqM@lS@vb@/Vxy5ms6HdQ7R2v/0HaZh5OvgwuoWzu9H6AcdPuD/Yc2ox0cKjhNRYCLH9AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 116 bytes

```python
def f(i):R=range(len(i)+1);print min([i[y:k+1]for y in R for k in R if(i[:y]+i[k+1:])[::-1]==i[:y]+i[k+1:]],key=len)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6xboMwFEX3fsWTJ1skFYYmIUbumClVpKyWBwOGvEId5BBV/npqK1O3e66O7ntzWG53V6xrZ3voKTJxld64wdLJuogZZ/Xs0S3wg44qVEGMGdf93UMAdHCFFMdXxDigRNAZqigJzZQQW66l/NfqzWiDjPNs/b3hZIELQJBxYn4ulNXwuofv0/fzsVC@YxmB7SfZ1Om/lVR5XpRlnlfkjXjT2tb40@VyjmSatrNd25iY3eDDGb6CH1wkXpQfu/2hOiYraY1JklJap4b8AQ)

Saved a couple of bytes with help from [Halvard Hummel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72350/halvard-hummel)!

Comment: [117 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY4xa8MwEIV3/4pDk4RbsOy2cRW0dkoJZBUaZFlxDidnI1xa/XpXolO37z0@3t2atttC7e6XMWjG2I4aaf3auDhedHQ0BX4PxFHUUlRrRNrggcQNmqTmWtrrEiEBElyg4PyHeOVoVLI1miwpK4xSz9Jq/a@1T3NIOs@LPV@uqu8b3gNIBeEneCgf7axvmrbrmqZnFYvOB@/ix/l8yskNfgyjH1xmmmI6wWeKE@Uk2@7l9e3QvxeraIMrkjHWlob9Ag)

Comment: @HalvardHummel Thanks, I was planning to change that too but didn’t have an internet connection for the last 2 hours.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>26</s> 22 bytes

```
¬£¬ËUjEY ê¬©UtEY
c æ+0
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rKOsy1VqRVkg6qypVXRFWQpjIOYrMA==&input=ImhlbGxoIiAtUQ==) Trying to figure out how to map `false` to something falsy and any string to something truthy in one byte. Currently I'm using `+0`...

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 108 bytes

```bash
for((j=0;;j++)){
for((i=0;i<${#1};i++)){
r=${1:0:i}${1:j+i}
[[ $r = `rev<<<$r` ]]&&echo "${1:i:j}"&&exit
}
}
```

Takes input as command-line argument.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxLCsMgFIXhuau4WJsoTpKp0R20KwiBtCWP68CUm1Aagmu3th0d@Dj899s6pydh2EYo@XnlJXAh07iQlN5VTeO1VupgP8AMaMVxqmODfycnjtpUBuN3vcbI2hYEgYOehpe1VlAPXVcUw2Necju/0PjIM7xxY5HFpHhKYaL9AtedpvAB) with quotes printed around the output for viewing leading/trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/), 271 byte

```
p([_]).
p([X,X]).
p([X|Y]):-append([P,[X]],Y),p(P).

s(P,M,S,R,N):-p(P),append([M,S],N).
s(P,M,S,S,N):-p(S),append([P,M],N).
s(P,M,S,P,M):-append([P,S],X),p(X).

d(Y,P,N):-
    findall([A,B,C],(append([R,M,X],Y),s(R,M,X,B,C),length(B,A)),S),
    sort(1,@>,S,[[_,P,N]|_]).
```

At some point I realized this is going to be huge by code-golf standards, so I kept a few extra blank spaces to preserve the resemblance to the non-obfuscated version.  But I still think it might be interesting since it's a different approach to the problem.

The non-obfuscated version:

```
palindrome([_]).
palindrome([X, X]).
palindrome([X | Xs]) :-
    append([Prefix, [X]], Xs),
    palindrome(Prefix).

palindrome_split(Prefix, Mid, Suffix, Prefix, N) :-
    palindrome(Prefix),
    append([Mid, Suffix], N).
palindrome_split(Prefix, Mid, Suffix, Suffix, N) :-
    palindrome(Suffix),
    append([Prefix, Mid], N).
palindrome_split(Prefix, Mid, Suffix, P, Mid) :-
    append([Prefix, Suffix], P),
    palindrome(P).

palindrome_downgrade(NP, P, N):-
    findall(
        [La, Pa, Na],
        (append([Prefix, Mid, Suffix], NP),
         palindrome_split(Prefix, Mid, Suffix, Pa, Na),
         length(Pa, La)),
        Palindromes),
    sort(1, @>, Palindromes, [[_, P, N] | _]).
```

Answer (score 2):

### C++, <s>254</s> <s>248</s> 246 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to Zacharý
-2 bytes thanks to Toby Speight

```cpp
#include<string>
#define S size()
#define T return
using s=std::string;int p(s t){for(int i=0;i<t.S;++i)if(t[i]!=t[t.S-i-1])T 0;T 1;}s d(s e){if(!p(e))for(int i,w=1;w<e.S;++w)for(i=0;i<=e.S-w;++i){s t=e;t.erase(i,w);if(p(t))T e.substr(i,w);}T"";}
```

So...

- I used `T` as a macro definition because doing `R""` as another effect on string literal ( it's a prefix used to define raw string literals, see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for more informations ) that is not there when i do `T""`
- Preprocessor definitions can't be on the same line, and have to have at least one space between the name and the content in the definition
- 2 functions : `p(std::string)` to test if the string is a palindrome. If it is, it returns `1` which casts to `true`, else it returns `0`, which casts to `false`
- The algorithm loops over the whole string testing if it's a palindrome when erasing each time 1 element, then test erasing 2 elements ( loops over that to the maximum size of the string ), from the first index to `the last index - number of erased char`. If it finds erasing some part is a palindrome, then, it returns. For example, when passing the string `"aabcdbaa"` as parameter, both `c` and `d` are valid answer, but this code will return `c` because erasing it and testing if it's a palindrome comes before testing if erasing `d` and testing if it's palindrome
- Here is the code to test :

  ```cpp
  std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> test{
      {"800233008","2"},
      { "racecarFOOL","FOOL" },
      { "abcdedcba","" },
      { "ngryL Myrgn","L " },
      { "123456789","12345678" },
      { "aabcdbaa","c" },
      { "[[]]","[[" },
      { "a","" },
      { "aabaab","b" }
  };

  for (const auto& a : test) {
      if (a.second != d(a.first)) {
          std::cout << "Error on : " << a.first << " - Answer : " << a.second  << " - Current : " << d(a.first) << '\n';
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Would this work for the last line? `using s=std::string;int p(s t){for(int i=0;i<t.S/2;++i)if(t[i]!=t[t.S-i-1])T 0;T 1;}s d(s e){if(!p(e))for(int i,w=1;w<e.S;++w)for(i=0;i<=e.S-w;++i){s t=e;t.erase(i,w);if(p(t))T e.substr(i,w);}T"";}`

Comment: Can the `/2` be omitted?  Iterating over the whole length will simply repeat the tests we've done, which should be harmless.  You might want to expand what you mean by the "other effect" of `R""` (i.e. it's parsed as a raw string literal).

Comment: I've modified this and added the result as an [answer of my own](/a/147419).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 33 bytes

```
r/ḟ@J}ị
“”µJp`ç³$ŒḂ$Ðfạ/ÞḢr/ịµŒḂ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/79I/@GO@Q5etQ93d3M9apjzqGHuoa1eBQmHlx/arHJ00sMdTSqHJ6Q93LVQ//C8hzsWAVXv7j60FSxh/////8Sk5JTUlOSkRAA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>91</s> 78 bytes

```
(s,i=0,j=0,S=[...s],b=S.splice(i,j))=>S+''==S.reverse()?b:f(s,s[++i]?i:!++j,j)
```

Input and output are lists of characters.

Recursively removes a larger and larger slice from the input until a palindrome is found.

**Snippet:**

```js
f=
(s,i=0,j=0,S=[...s],b=S.splice(i,j))=>S+''==S.reverse()?b:f(s,s[++i]?i:!++j,j)


console.log(f([...'800233008']).join``)   // 2
console.log(f([...'racecarFOOL']).join``) // FOOL
console.log(f([...'abcdedcba']).join``)   // (empty string)
console.log(f([...'ngryL Myrgn']).join``) // "L " (or " M")
console.log(f([...'123456789']).join``)   // 12345678 (or 23456789)
console.log(f([...'aabcdbaa']).join``)    // c (or d)
console.log(f([...'[[]]']).join``)        // [[ (or ]])
console.log(f([...'a']).join``)           // (empty string)
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 104+1 bytes

```php
while(~($s=$argn)[$e+$i++]?:++$e|$i=0)strrev($t=substr_replace($s,"",$i,$e))==$t&&die(substr($s,$i,$e));
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f9d2e103b0a075a7cf59bcfaf3c43ba72a1e263c).

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 72 +1 (-p) bytes

```
$\=$_;/.*(?{$,=$`.$';$\=$&if length$&<length$\&&$,eq reverse$,})(?!)/g}{
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxlYl3lpfT0vDvlpFx1YlQU9F3RokqJaZppCTmpdekqGiZgNlxKipqeikFioUpZalFhWnqujUamrYK2rqp9dW//9vYWBgYGRsbGBg8S@/oCQzP6/4v24BAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>109</s> 105 bytes

```hs
snd.minimum.([]#)
p#s@(a:b)=[(i,take i s)|i<-[0..length s],(==)<*>reverse$p++drop i s]++(p++[a])#b
p#_=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczRTsMgGIbhc6@CtB6A7QiuulUzjEcebdkFIFl@KO3IChKoJku8dnHt4fPlzXeGdDHjmHv@mZPvqLPeum9HsZAluQtlesfwqggX2NYTXAyyKJFfu1sJRulo/DCdUZI15pzsHt6i@TExmftQVV38CnMsqwrfKECSUt0OT1zI7MB6xJGDcDghHKL1E@0JEkXL2LppGGuLGhURtNEQP47H/UxQujOdVjDDD/G6R4drHPzMx3Xz9LzZti9LOJcKlk4IKZetkPlP9yMMKa90CP8)

EDIT: Thanks @H.PWiz for taking off 4 bytes! I need to get better with those monads!

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>98</s> <s>94</s> <s>81</s> 80 bytes

```hs
""#0
(h#n)t|(==)=<<reverse$h++drop n t=take n t|x:r<-t=(h++[x])#n$r|m<-n+1=t#m$h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/LboMwELz7K1aGA1aKRKCPtMI99pQoH@ByMMaFKMGxjFUlKv31UhsaEqkry96dmdWMG97t5eEw1PR9wDhIUNQEitg@opTQPDfyU5pOhs1iUZmjBgWWWr6XvulPLyaPLY0cyU4FCVRo@jaP1WJJbdCGzdDynQIK2uyUhRBarqEGhldJkmZZkqzwHTZcSMHN23a7dhMvRSUrUXLXq9qc17A5m1q5aZlm9w@PT6tnr/KyknsRY0XhkQl1BxcIfcVotgCA@BVSdOPjAf@i2W0SRbLV9gyddXFrgm78PYvXgCE6GndvMEFznmn3Mo6KC0XQJSlMKjHSFUE@NvyVwxkbiaJwG3Ct/5mmP85sieLv4Ud8HHjdDbHQ@hc) Example usage: `""#0 $ "aabaab"` yields `"b"`.

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to  Ørjan Johansen.*

Comment: You can replace the last `""` by `t`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 90 bytes

```
a=>a.map((_,p)=>a.map((_,q)=>k||(t=(b=[...a]).splice(q,p),k=''+b==b.reverse()&&t)),k=0)&&k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLboMwEEX3/QpW8VgEy4SmpQtnV1ap8gEINeNHEIHajkGRIuXfKSm0qjSLOfce3TNesVeh8UNinTbjSYwodsi@0AN8rj39B5cJ2vsdBgFSlIwxrCjrfdcoA5dJXbeCkFgKIVkwVxN6A3S1Guij4NPXjoWYxpWzvesM61wNyDzqd6shTWlMoiRJdhGJT/C7fnaNPR7pUwEk53yTZZzn5AcDKqMwFIfDfg5QKm20kjijrcNtH33cQm3nIN1kz9uX1/xt0R@@xMUuy6pa8r96OkLHbw)

```js
f=
a=>a.map((_,p)=>a.map((_,q)=>k||(t=(b=[...a]).splice(q,p),k=''+b==b.reverse()&&t)),k=0)&&k

F=a=>console.log(a.padEnd(11)+' ---> '+f([...a]).join``)
F('800233008')
F('racecarFOOL')
F('abcdedcba')
F('ngryL Myrgn')
F('123456789')
F('aabcdbaa')
F('[[]]')
F('a')
F('aabaab')
```

Answer (score 1):

## TSQL (2016) 349B

Not the most compact but straightforward solution:

```
DECLARE @i VARCHAR(255)='racecarFOOL'
;WITH DAT(v,i,l)AS(SELECT value,(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY value))-1,LEN(@i)FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(@i+';',LEN(@i)+1),';')WHERE value<>'')
SELECT TOP 1C,S
FROM(SELECT LEFT(D.v, D.i)+SUBSTRING(D.v,D.i+E.i+1,D.l)C,SUBSTRING(D.v,D.i+1,E.i)S
FROM DAT D CROSS APPLY DAT E)C
WHERE C=REVERSE(C)
ORDER BY LEN(C)DESC
```

Comment: You can use `@` as a variable for a few bytes.  In the CTE you can use `where''=value)` for another one and you don't need to return `C` in the result.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <s>189</s> <s>186</s> <s>176</s> 167 bytes

I started with [HatsuPointerKun's answer](/a/147373), changing the test to simply compare equality with reversed string; then I changed how we enumerate the candidate strings.  Following this, the macros were only used once or twice each, and it was shorter to inline them.

```c++
#include<string>
using s=std::string;s d(s e){for(int i,w=0;;++w){s t=e.substr(w);for(i=-1;++i<=t.size();t[i]=e[i])if(t==s{t.rbegin(),t.rend()})return e.substr(i,w);}}
```

### Explanation

Equivalent readable code:

```c++
std::string downgrade(std::string e)
{
    for (int w=0; ; ++w) {
        std::string t = e.substr(w);
        for (int i=0;  i<=t.size();  ++i) {
            if (t == std::string{t.rbegin(),t.rend()})
                // We made a palindrome by removing w chars beginning at i
                return e.substr(i,w);
            t[i] = e[i];  // next candidate
        }
    }
}
```

The enumeration of candidates begins by initialising a string with the first `w` characters omitted, and then copying successive characters from the original to move the gap.  For example, with the string `foobar` and `w`==2:

```
foobar
  ↓↓↓↓
  obar
```

```
foobar
↓
fbar
```

```
foobar
 ↓
foar
```

```
foobar
  ↓
foor
```

```
foobar
   ↓
foob
```

The first pass (with `w`==0) is a no-op, so the full string will be considered over and over again.  That's fine - golfing trumps efficiency!  The last iteration of this loop will access the one-past-the-end index; I seem to get away with that with GCC, but strictly, that's Undefined Behaviour.

### Test program

A direct lift from [HatsuPointerKun's answer](/a/147373):

```c++
static const std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> test{
    { "800233008", "2" },
    { "racecarFOOL", "FOOL" },
    { "abcdedcba", "" },
    { "ngryL Myrgn", "L " },
    { "123456789", "12345678" },
    { "aabcdbaa", "c" },
    { "[[]]", "[[" },
    { "a","" },
    { "aabaab", "b" }
};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    for (const auto& a : test) {
        if (a.second != d(a.first)) {
            std::cout << "Error on: " << a.first
                      << " - Expected: " << a.second
                      << " - Actual: " << d(a.first) << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest `rbegin(x)` and `rend(x)` instead of `x.rbegin()` and `x.rend()`

Comment: I think the associated `#include<iterator>` will outweigh the gains.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 18 bytes

```
◄LfmS=↔†!⁰ṠM-Qŀ⁰Q⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9H0Fp@03GDbR21THjUsUHzUuOHhzgW@uoFHG4DMQCD@//@/UmJiEhApAQA)

### Explanation

```
◄LfmS=↔†!⁰ṠM-Qŀ⁰Q⁰  Input is a string, say s="aab"
              ŀ⁰    Indices of s: x=[1,2,3]
             Q      Slices: [[],[1],[1,2],[2],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]
          ṠM-       Remove each from x: [[1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[1,3],[],[1],[1,2]]
       †!⁰          Index into s: ["aab","ab","b","ab","","a","aa"]
   mS=↔             Check which are palindromes: [0,0,1,0,1,1,1]
  f             Q⁰  Filter the slices of s by this list: ["aa","aab","ab","b"]
◄L                  Minimum on length: "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>86</s> 84 bytes

```ruby
->s{l=i=0
(l+=(i+=1)/z=s.size-l+1
i%=z)while(w=s[0,i]+s[i+l..-1])!=w.reverse
s[i,l]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcrNjoIwGIXhfa@idjIBUqgF5gcXn8tZabyApotSqzZpzKRFCSDXjhrYnfPk9be6m04wZdswOLDAUewoxJZCnqx7CCzY3mSO5sh@Qp@0F@tM3EIQPLWSBmGpYyzLZbKClnlzNz4Y9OLUyXESCGNScV6UJecVSd/XK2208n@Hw24GVeujOepazfd69t0O7zt/vs6QF@XX989vtVnyd1@rpRZCysUJkswofcHDo3ng/1sTMIk@hmaMcLbFr3USjRwjMk5P)

- Saved 2 bytes thanks to Cyoce

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around `z=s.size-l+1`.

Comment: @Cyoce Thank you. I have a hard time remembering all the operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 132 bytes

```
a=arg(1)
l=length(a)
do i=1 to l
  do j=0 to l-i+1
    b=delstr(a,i,j)
    if b=reverse(b) & m>j then do
      m=j
      s=substr(a,i,j)
      end
    end
  end
say s
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 307 bytes

```c
#define T malloc(K)
P(S,i,y,z,k,u,L,K,V)char*S;{char*M,*R,*E;K=strlen(S);M=T;R=T;E=T;for(i=0;i<K;++i){for(y=0;y<=K-i;++y){strcpy(M,S);for(z=y;z<y+i;E[z-y]=M[z],++z);for(k=y;k+i<=K;M[k]=M[k+i],++k);V=strlen(M);strcpy(R,M);for(u=0;u<V/2;L=R[u],R[u]=R[V-u-1],R[V-u-1]=L,++u);if(!strcmp(M,R))puts(E),exit(0);}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVDLboMwELznK2h68cKi5tXT4iMnYikiEReUQ0RIa5EASnBVg/h2um7alfY1oxmvXIQfRTFNr@fyouvSO3i30/XaFCKB2U7sUaPFHis0uMUEMyg@T3d/T8NvV@in6MeUyEd3v5a12AMpeaCUM@a8NHeh5YJ0lFAQaBgcYBmwkUxCzZiFgaVFa4VCFju@l5b6yAaa4rwP7VGqvD9iEPRPumK6CjQbkMorx/Lm@Aoo@79DAf3ZpqieOsPPmih7W9FWprk5ois8ZaEJl257DnLLVgZIX8SLs7i1fFkK0JruIWLA8lt3YgE0juOk645/S9fiq9Fn8IaZx7ET8@VqvXnfrFfLOdBsnH4A)

Comment: [259 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3NbsIwEITvfYqUkxdv1PzQlsr4SC9JBApSLlEOjgnUKiTIJJUsRF89daBI8cHj/dYzI929lH2/JhtUaPAbO4wxwgzkl9DTDbvcNOFSHA6NJBE/t/pQ1WQD1McQcJryhEY4XfKURq7Ldo0mintMLSJGqYJhNnY2Cx65yiIDl1I2J0NskLSSoI0yuEQF7L5IqKEK7Y0R9V3lGmDZo/bflGICcOvqbHa3yF4CluZdwdM8o79dgVZdSi2IIebDhqkdeR7cx5OtTAF01Xa6dk5deyZLYNdrr@rWOQpVk59GbcG5PDn2rMnED8LZ6ywM/AmwB9NCVlLoz9UqHtG55wVh6HnzEROl3FZbWYoRq/faxE5i9L4e0VvP2/v8Y@we7KUYm/O8KMY/hve1/wM "C (gcc) – Try It Online")